# How to push segue from cell click in table view to another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have one table view controller and by clicking the cell i am redirecting the user to detail view controller.But when i perform segue " present view controller" its working fine.But what i need is?

I need to perform push segue by clicking the table view cell.How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: BusinessDetailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BusinessDetailViewController") as! BusinessDetailViewController
        vc.BusinessData = arrDict[indexPath.row]
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
```

I have tried this below line :

```
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

But it doesn't work.Any Solution Please !!

Comment: I din't perform any drag and drop and i din't set any identifier name.I need to perform fully programatically.I refered hat also.But it din't help me

Comment: Is your current view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 12):

First of all your `UITableViewController` must have a `UINavigationController`

To do it rapidly embedded it to your table from the xCode menu

[image]:

Then , you must create the segue, ctrl-drag from the `UITableViewController` to the destination viewController:

[image]

Then select the segue and give it an identifier in the property inspector:

[image]

Now you are able to perform this segue in code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: cell)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using `UINavigationController` than add a `segue` in `storyboard` from table cell to destination `viewController` and give a `identifier` to `segue`.

then on cell click call

```
- performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
```

and implement

```
- prepareForSegue:sender:
```

Comment: Thanks @jagdish this worked for me!  I dragged from the Cell, selected in the outline view, to the View Controller, gave the segue an Identifier and then passed it in to performSegue(). Note that I'm not doing anything yet with the data in my example as its a Work in Progress to learn Swift. But the segue is working: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let section = indexPath.section
             
        performSegue(withIdentifier: “MySegueID”, sender: self)
                
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Without a navigation controller it's not possible to push a controller. Your `self.navigationController` property is `nil` (you can check it)

How to solve it?

A :You need to embed your view controller in navigation controller either via code or via storyboard

Comment: in code.How to call my current view controoler with navigation controller.Beacuse there are more viewcontrollers.So if i do it now via storyboard.Sure my all views will get affect

Answer (score 0):

try this code, its working for me,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayViewController") as! PlayViewController

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
```

and set the storyboard Id, example given below,

[image]

hope its helpful